# Suggest Custom SonarQube rules for AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sonarqube, rules

I am writing an application in AngularJs, Javascript and jQuery. I installed SonarQube to run analysis. It gave me pretty good resukts and I was able to update my code based on the errors shown by SonarQube.

However, I want to write custom rules for my code which are not there in SonarQube. Can anyone suggest me some examples for the same. I am new to SonarQube.

Answer (score 1):

Some documentation for writing custom rules https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+SonarJS

Example project https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/tree/master/javascript-custom-rules

For more examples of rules see SonarJS itself https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript/tree/master/javascript-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/javascript/checks

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links. But I am looking for suggestions of some custom rules which are not there in SonarQube list of rules for AngularJS

Comment: First, there is no rules in SonarQube (SonarJS plugin) specifically targeting AngularJS, they are mostly about javascript only. So if you want some inspiration for rule ideas look here https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-angular#rules